# Knockout template and unique ID within complex web app causing problems

Tags: javascript, templates, knockout.js

Knockout templating system is great, however in a web app where there are **several separated contexts** ("views") that are loaded by ajax, one issue appears:

> Templates rely on ID

This means that if my chance you have one template with the same name on a view that on another view loaded previously and still existing in the webapp context, knockout (because the browser does this) will take the first matching #templateId element.

On our webapp, we eliminated the ID of all our elements, and when it really needs to be used, it's an ID that is javascript determined to not have duplicates.

> Some views can be loaded multiple times in the lifetime of the app, so
>   **no**, we can't say "**simply check if the id is already used before making your html code**" to our team members.

The only other thing we could do would be to check if a specific template is loaded, and if not load it in async, then apply bindings. But for simplicity purpose and the way our project is set up right now, we can't apply an js AMD-like dependency manager.

### Questions

- **Is that possible to specify directly the DOM reference to the template directly?**

  `data-bind="template:function(){ return $('yourSelectorToTheTemplate')[0]; }"`

I've looked knockout code and it's weird because we have this:

```
templateDocument = templateDocument || document;
        var elem = templateDocument.getElementById(template);
        if (!elem)
            throw new Error("Cannot find template with ID " + template);
        return new ko.templateSources.domElement(elem);
```

This means that it really use the DOM element, so why being forced to give an ID for it if we already have the ID?

- **How do we retrieve dynamically applied IDtemplate, that is also calling another dynamically applied ID (template recursively calling itself for example)?**

Setting ID from a binding handler may be wrong: it may set the ID after other data bound elements referred to it, but it would be simpler to have to.

Comment: have you tried with `class name`

Comment: There are template engines that do not use the Dom as template source.  Like https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bootstrap.TemplateStore/wiki

Comment: While I understand your will to remove ids on DOM elements, templates are different and I really don't see why you would have two templates with the same id. If you have multiple views, just prefix the template's id with the name of the view or something. Unless your templates are generated on the fly?

Comment: @GôTô the problem is that it happens in a team project, people can use the same ID and not be aware of other pending changes, and at commit you always have the possibility to have duplicates (and further more, I prefer having a rule like "DO NOT USE ID" (which I already am) instead of having to often check if there are duplicates). Plus yes, I do have some templates generated on the fly, but they're not that bad to handle since they're generated by JS I always can check if the ID is used or not.

Comment: I think it would be less trouble to come up with a good naming convention. As for the generated ones, on second thought, it does not change much

Comment: @Anders Yes I understand, but I think that knockout could easily accept DOM out of the box, since their standard templating engine gets the ID and use a DOM node.

Comment: @GôTô As I said in my original post, a view can be loaded multiple times, then its containing elements can be duplicated in the html page, that's the worst case, but it happens, nothing prevents it. It's not even a naming convention problem in that case, and as nothing gets commited fast, it would be hard to check after each commit if there are duplicates (plus I'm sure that it's something that can easily be forgotten in the case of a rush)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution found for the moment:

1. Place templates (script element) at the top of the html view.
2. Use a bindingHandler that does initialization (I called mine "init" as you can see in the example below) to set the ID of the script element
3. Store that ID inside the $root context so it can be reused by other elements

The result looks like this:

```
<script type="text/html" data-bind="init: function(){ $rawData.folderItemTemplate = functionThatSetsAndReturnsUniqueId($element, 'folderItemTemplate'); }">
        <li> 
            Some item
            <ul data-bind="template: { name: $rawData.folderItemTemplate, foreach: children }"></ul>
        </li>
    </script>
```

As you can see we can use this template binding with template: { name: $rawData.yourPropertyName, foreach:... }